# Query Regarding Kconfig: Structure of "default" element

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild, kconfig

In the Kconfig snippet provided below:

```kbuild
config USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD
boolean
default y if USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI
default PCI
```

I'm curious about the structure of the last line, which differs from the preceding lines. Instead of being written as:

```kbuild
default y if PCI
```

Could someone explain why the last line in this Kconfig code is structured differently?

Comment: `PCI` can be _n_ (actually not defined) or _y_.  This is _n_ if `PCI=n` and `USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI=n`, otherwise `USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y` by default. But, it can be also _y_ when another code selects it, while `PCI=n` and `USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI=n` (in case that code is not dependent to these two).